# Why isn't my picture showing anymore

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

This morning I was testing my out my program and just running it through and it was working well. After an hour my images just stopped appearing on my buttons I'm not sure why.

```
JButton chuck = new JButton(new ImageIcon("chucknorris.jpg"));//this part of program runs this if user picks lizard
chuck.setSize(210,175); //sets size of button
chuck.setLocation(25,75); //sets location of button
chuck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
        int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "\t\t                  STATS\nAttack:      10\nDefence:   15\nspecial:   bomb");

        if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("No button clicked");
        } else if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            x = 1;
            b = 0;
        } else if (answer == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("JOptionPane closed");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging.

Comment: Where are your images stored? I'd also discourage you from using `null` layouts

Comment: my images are stored in a folder with my java file

Comment: Try to put the image on the folder which stores the .class file

Answer (score 2):

> my images are stored in a folder with my java file

This suggests that the images are, in fact, embedded resources and can't be referenced like normal files on the file system.

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the `String` reference is referring to a file on the file system.  Once built, this will no longer be `true`, instead, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourcesAsStream` depending on your needs, for example...

```
JButton chuck = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("chucknorris.jpg")));
```

A better solution would be to use `ImageIO.read` as this will actually throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason, rather than failing silently

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("chucknorris.jpg"));
    JButton chuck = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img));
} catch (IOException exp) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check has left the building");
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```